# Parsing Attribute Macro Arguments in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm writing an attribute macro and trying to parse arguments passed there.

Like: `#[macro(Arg1, Arg2)]`

The issue is that I cannot find the right structure to parse it as. I tried parsing it as `Meta` and `MetaList` but none of them seem to work.

```rust
pub fn some_macro(args: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
let args_parsed = parse_macro_input!(args as MetaList);

////////

let args_parsed = parse_macro_input!(args as Meta);

}
```

When I parse it as `MetaList` I get: "unexpected end of input, expected parentheses" Error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you use the `syn` crate.

---

Proc macros don't get their arguments as a meta, but after stripping the `#[name(...)]`. That is, `args` will contain `Arg1, Arg2` and not `#[macro(Arg1, Arg2)]` which is what `Meta` (and `MetaList`) expect.

What you want is [`Punctuated`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/punctuated/struct.Punctuated.html):

```rust
// Note that I put `syn::Path` but you can put whatever you want to parse between the commas.
// For example `syn::NestedMeta` if you want the full attribute syntax.
let args_parsed = syn::punctuated::Punctuated::<syn::Path, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated
    .parse(args)
    .unwrap(); // Better to turn it into a `compile_error!()`
```

Comment: My question is that in `Punctuated<DATATYPE, SEPERATOR>` what if I don't want a separator that is, I just want one argument.

Comment: @random_hooman `Punctuated<DATATYPE, SEPERATOR>` addresses a *list* of things - if you just want one, use `DATATYPE` directly. For a single item, you can `parse_macro_input!(args as Meta)`

Answer (score 1):

For a style closer to what you expect, `parse_macro_input!` supports the `with` keyword:

```rust
let args = parse_macro_input!(args with Punctuated::<Meta, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated);
```